# Passing arguments with action client

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, action-server, action-client, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to control an Franka Emika robot using action servers.
https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/ros_introduction.html
The gripper Operation franka_gripper::HomingAction() is working with:

```
 actionlib::SimpleActionClient<franka_gripper::HomingAction> ac("franka_gripper/homing", true);
 ROS_INFO("Waiting for action server to start.");
 bool success=ac.isServerConnected(); //will wait for infinite time
 if (success)
   {ROS_INFO("Verbindung hergestellt");}
 ac.waitForServer(); 
 ROS_INFO("Action server started, sending goal.");
 franka_gripper::HomingGoal goal;
 ac.sendGoal(goal);
```

Now I would like to use the MoveAction as descriped in the documentation where I have to pass the arguments for width and speed. However I don't get how to do this. I checked the MoveGoal.msg which tells that two floats are needed. I tried to set them with:

> ac.sendGoal(width, speed);

which is not working. Analogously to the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient) I used goal.order= in different variation like

> goal.order {width, speed};

but it seems not to know the order function. So my question is how I can set this parameters correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290053/passing-arguments-with-action-client/) by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should start with some basic programming tutorials before working with a robot where wrong commands can lead to unsafe movements and injury. (or are you working only in simulation?)

But about your question, it should be simply:

```
goal.width = 0.05; 
ac.sendgoal(goal);
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Krebsileinchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34851/krebsileinchen/) on 2018-05-03**:
Oh sure.. thank you. No worries I am save.